# Usage of the word 'adroitly'

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, adverbs

Is it correct to say that a barkeep was *"**adroitly** pouring out drinks behind the bar"*? Something rubs me the wrong way here. Perhaps it would be better to use some synonym in this context? If so, which one?

Comment: It's true that [deftly poured](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22deftly+poured%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is ten times more likely than [adroitly poured](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adroitly+poured%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but why should the less common usage rub you up the wrong way?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why, but as noted below, _adroitly_ seems too formal for this context. Thanks for your links, though! Comparing them to [neatly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neatly+poured%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [expertly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22expertly+poured%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [nimbly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nimbly+poured%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I'm going to stick with _deftly_.

Comment: I don't think "formality" is really the relevant concept here. It's just that [**deftly** has gradually displaced **adroitly** and **dexterously**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deftly%2Cadroitly%2Cdexterously&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) over the past century and a half. But note that all three of those (relatively uncommon) words usually imply *skilled **handling***, which is not the case with alternatives such as *neatly, expertly, nimbly,* etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with this usage. But I agree it is stilted. My preference would be for ***expertly*** or ***neatly***.

Comment: "Neatly" might work, but it hints at a double meaning here, even if it's unintended.

Comment: Don't think 'neatly' can be used in the same sense of 'neat' - unless there is yet another implication that eludes me?

Comment: Probably not, but it wouldn't be a stretch for someone to consider it to be a pun, even if it wasn't meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely grammatically correct. I suspect that it is the fact that *adroitly* is very formal and is not commonly used in everyday speech that is making it sound incorrect to you. To be honest, if I were speaking about a bartender, I wouldn't use the word adroitly, but that's simply my personal preference; that doesn't make it incorrect.

[Expertly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/adroitly), proficiently, and masterfully would all work in that sentence. There are many other [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/adroitly) as well.

Comment: thanks for the comment. My question was not about the grammar, but about word choice. I'm not a native speaker, so I often don't quite feel the nuances of meaning. I was referring to physical smoothness in the original sentence, so how would _nimbly_ fit in?

Comment: There's very little difference in meaning between expertly, masterfully, skilfully, (and many other synonyms) and adroitly. Often there are subtle nuances or starkly different connotations in words with similar definitions; however, in the specific example that you've cited, all of the synonyms that I have mentioned make almost no difference in the meaning. All express the same idea, which is that the bartender is an expert or that s/he does an exceptionally fine job  preparing  cocktails. As a native speaker of American English, it sounds odd to me too, but only because of the formality.